# Can a primary key of a subclass table be referenced as a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database, ddl

I'm currently working on a mysql project for my class and I'm wondering if the PK-FK of a subclass table can be referenced as FK for another table instead of the PK of the parent class.

Let's say I have the subclass table *employees* written as:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    Person_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Designation varchar(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (Person_ID) REFERENCES persons(Person_ID));
```

As for the parent class,

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    Person_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Last_Name varchar(255),
    Middle_Name varchar(255),
    First_Name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(Person_ID));
```

Let's say I want to create another table *works* whose FK references Person_ID from the subclass *employees*, not the parent class *persons*.

```
CREATE TABLE works (
    project_ID PRIMARY KEY,
    date_started date,
    FOREIGN KEY (Person_ID) REFERENCES employees(Person_ID));
```

Thanks!

Comment: In databases there is no such thing as "classses" and "subclasses". There are tables.

Comment: mysql has no identody

Comment: @nbk ah, my bad. Will update it.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, perhaps I should rephrase but I'm referring to the concept of generalization/specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's technically possible (I guess you tested that already) and is logically also OK in such a case as yours. In fact referencing `persons` would be wrong if, logically, only employees can take part in the "works on" relation -- the FK constraint wouldn't ensure that they're only employees.

Comment: I see, that's great to hear. Thanks! I actually haven't tested it as I'm only manually encoding it on a word file and haven't created the database yet ^^

Comment: @mariefherv: Side note: o_O Don't use Word! Use some plain text editor (I can recommend SciTE, but there are a lot to chose from. Even plain Windows Notepad is better than Word.). Word has the habit to replace certain characters with a "fancy" version, e.g. quotes and dashes. If you then copy and paste the code form there to execute it, you'll get errors because of that.

Comment: Haha yes, don't worry! I use Sublime mostly and this is just one of the few instances I use Word for the activity since our instructor requires it on a PDF file. ^^

Answer (score 0):

It is no Problem, but you have always check if the id exist.

Ring connection can cause problems.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE persons (
>     Person_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     Last_Name varchar(255),
>     Middle_Name varchar(255),
>     First_Name varchar(255),
>     PRIMARY KEY(Person_ID));
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees (
>     Person_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
>     Designation varchar(50),
>     foreign key (Person_ID) REFERENCES persons(Person_ID));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE works (
>     project_ID Int PRIMARY KEY,
>     date_started date,
>     Person_ID int,
>     FOREIGN KEY (Person_ID) REFERENCES employees(Person_ID));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTo persons VALUES (NULL,'A','B','C')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1,'test')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO works  VALUES (1,NOW(),1)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8d1ac07141af1b223cd36f356302fac)*

Comment: Ah, I see that I forgot to add NOT NULL on my PK for persons. Also, thanks for recommending the tool! It's a great help since I don't have a database to test on it yet. ^^ Cheers!